# EntityFramework (Data Annotations only) Relationship not resolving with ID

Tags: c#, entity-framework, annotations, in-memory-database

I have the relationship of two classes.

```cs
class ClassA {
   [Required]
   int Id { get; set; }

   [Required]
   public int OtherId { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("OtherId")]
   public ClassB? Other{ get; set; }
}
```

```cs
class ClassB {
   [Required]
   int Id { get; set; }

   public IEnumerable<ClassA> Others { get; set; } = new List<ClassA>();
}
```

When I insert an object of `ClassA` I do it like this:

```cs
await this.Context.Set<ClassA>().AddAsync(new ClassA() { OtherId = 2 } );
await this.Context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

This works perfectly on the live database (Azure SQL DB). When I add the class like this and fetch it from the database later on (e.g. literally after the `SaveChangesAsync`), I get the object, INCLUDING the object `ClassA.Other`.

When I run the code on an in-memory DB on the other hand, it does not work! The inserting step works, but does NOT validate if the ID (`ClassA.OtherId`) exists. This means, I can set the `ClassA.OtherId` to "12345" without any problems, even if I do not have a single entry of `ClassB`. If I insert a valid `ClassA.OtherId` it works as well, but when I fetch the object from the database, `ClassA.Other` is null.

Just to clarify, why I write `ClassB? Other` instead of `ClassB Other`. This is only a simplified version of the code, I tested quickly, but in our production environment, we include/exclude certain fields from certain queries for performance reasons. Therefore, it is possible that the property might be null at certain times.

Comment: I fear that are the downsides of using in-memory-databases for tests, they cant do everything a real db might... what do you use for the in-memory testdouble?

Comment: What we often do is not use an in-memory provider but the sqlite provider, if you never save the file it's almost as fast as any in-memory db + you could save the file on errors to analyze

Comment: Thanks @FlorianSchmidinger. We use the in-memory DB for our unit tests and we just recently discovered this flaw.

Comment: yeah but just the default one from microsoft?... there are more capable libraries out there... but they all share some flaws...

Comment: Oh sorry. Yes, we use the default microsoft solution.

Comment: Using the sqlite provider instead is an option?

Comment: I just tried it the moment you suggested it and without any problems it works now. Thanks for your guidance! Do you want to write the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most In-memory Testdoubles have some flaws in that regard, instead try to use the SQlite Provider, for it behaves more like a real Database

Example for the Configuration:

```
public static class EfDbContextSqliteBuilderConfigurationFactory
{
    internal static Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> GetSqliteDatabaseOption()
    {
        const string tempDataBaseFolder = "Database";
        EnsureSqliteTempDatabaseFolderExists(tempDataBaseFolder);

        return c => c.UseSqlite(new SqliteConnection($"DataSource={tempDataBaseFolder}\\{Guid.NewGuid()}.db"));
    }

    private static void EnsureSqliteTempDatabaseFolderExists(string tempDataBaseFolder)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(tempDataBaseFolder))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(tempDataBaseFolder);
        }
    }
}
```